# fzero of two functions subtracted

Tags: matlab

I am writing a code for calculating fzero of the subtraction of two functions.
Just take a very simple example

```
fun1 = @(x) x^3;
fun2 = @(x) x^2;
fun = fun1(x) - fun2(x);
fzero(@(x)fun,1)
```

Always errors were shown, what should be the correct syntax?
Could you help me please?

Comment: `fun = @(x) fun1(x) - fun2(x)`

Comment: Error still exists

Comment: Sorry, then `fzero(fun,1)` should do it

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't help.

Comment: How does it still not help? It works fine. What mystical errors are you speaking of?

Answer (score 0):

```
fun1 = @(x) x.^3;
fun2 = @(x) x.^2;
fun = @(x) fun1(x) - fun2(x);
fzero(fun,1)
```